# Find Next Non Zero Values In A Column With Its Subscription

Tags: excel, formula

I've a question regarding columns and finding non zero values with there labels.
Hopefully the pictures will make my problem/struggle a bit better to understand.

[image: Overview]

Basically, there are columns to the right that show labels and hours that a team loaned in or out.
The values are found through a formula that shows per label the totals amount of hours spent.

Now I want to have on my overview page the two columns to the right with only labels showing the labels that contain hours. I've tried to use multiple if variables but that didn't seem to work :(

So at the end it should show something like this (I now manually typed the labels and data):

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a quick recreation of your data structure to test this.

Using [Array Formulas](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7) should get you the desired results in the current structure of your worksheet:

For range `Loaned in` you'd need the formula to be

```
=IFERROR(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(SMALL(IF($I$4:$I$14>0,ROW($4:$14),""),ROW(A1)),8)),"")
```

Where `8` is a reference to the return column. For the range directly to the right, you'd use the same formula, just adjust `8` to `9`. And for range `Loaned Out` you'd need

```
=IFERROR(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(SMALL(IF($K$4:$K$23>0,ROW($4:$23),""),ROW(A1)),10)),"")
```

And for the range directly to the right you would again change the `10` to a `11`. Again, both of these are array formulas, so they have to entered slightly differently. See the link for further assistance with array formulas.

Answer (score 0):

This is not trivial. If you cannot work with filtering or programming, you should make use of matrix formulas. I include an example with two formulas: 1st in D1:D5, 2nd in F2:G5. Enter them with Ctrl+Shift+Enter. Also, you should use an extra column to determine the "valid" rows. (You could put it all in one formula, but it would look even more complicated.)

Sorry for German excel. Wennfehler = iferror, kkleinste = small, zeile = row, wenn = if, bereich.verschieben = range.offset.

[image: ][2]]

[image: ][1]]

Comment: Both of you're options worked for me! Thank you for your response and I am now using the one of Tate! Yet again, thank you all for your help :)